# Looks different in reality vs visa photo

Tags: usa, transit-visas, airport-security

I'm going to fly to the United States in october.
The problem is that i got my visa 1.5 years ago when I had short hair and beard.
Will it be a problem that I have now a longer hair and beard?
I'm also going to renew my passport soon so I need to know if I must cut my hair for the new passport so the pictures in the passport and visa will be the same or I can keep growing my hair.

edit: The problem is I do not own a biometric passport yet, and some of my friends had warned me about that the haircut can cause problems and they can even decide to not let me enter to the country. I don't know what should I do

Answer (score 3):

Both the Visa Information System for embassies and Border Control officers have your biometric records. You don't have to be worried as your fingers are going to be scanned on entry and compared to retrieved data from the VIS database.

Plus: The U.S. government uses a sophisticated image processing algorithm for face recognition and it can easily identify face patterns even with beards/different haircuts/plastic surgeries and face expressions.